# Spark's createDataset(List<T>, Encoder<T>) returning empty dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to convert a list of object to `Dataset<Row>` using `Encoders.bean` in spark but getting empty data set every time I am running the following code even though my list contains data of type T(java pojo).

```
Dataset<Row> d = getSparkSession()
      .createDataset(myListOfObject, Encoders.bean(MyObject.class)).toDF()
```

I am expecting the conversion of `myListOfObject` to be converted to `Dataset<Row>`.

Comment: can you add more complete example? Add the code that shows creation of `myListOfObject` and some sample values added to it.